# $G$ diffeomorphic to $G\times\{p\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Given two smooth manifold $G$ and $M$,we know $G\times \{p\}$ is embedded sobmanifold for $G\times M$.

Now prove $G$ diffeomorphic to $G\times \{p\}$

My attempt: canonical projection $\pi:G\times M \to G$ is smooth surjective submersion,hence restriction on embedded submanifold $G\times \{p\}$ is also smooth,and easy to see it's bijective on the restriction.

Now comes the problem,how to show inverse is also smooth,I know for inverse $(\pi|_{G\times \{p\}})^{-1}:g \to (g,p)$ with coordinate representation we can show it's smooth.How to show inverse is smooth without coordinate chart?

Comment: why do you not want to use coordinates?

Comment: Try using that the inclusion $g\mapsto (g,p)$ is a smooth embedding (i.e. a topological embedding which is also an immersion).

Comment: @Darth Lubinus Do you mean inclusion from $G\to G\times M$? and restriction the codomain?

Comment: @Darth Lubinus doesn't proving it is a smooth embedding require coordinates?

Comment: Yes. I'll write an answer without coordinates in a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $p\in M$. For the sake of notation, I'll denote $i\colon G\to G\times M$ as the map $i(g)=(g,p)$ and $\pi\colon G\times M\to G$ as $\pi(x,y)=x$. We have to prove that $i$ is a smooth embedding from $G$ to $G\times \{p\}$.

First, we prove that $i$ is an immersion: since $\pi \circ i=\operatorname{Id}_{G}$, by the chain rule we have that $\pi_{*(g,p)}\circ i_{*g}=(\operatorname{Id}_{G})_{*g}=\operatorname{Id}_{T_{g}(G)}$, which implies that $i_{*g}$ is injective for every $g\in G$. Therefore, $i$ is an immersion.

In order to prove that $i$ is a topological embedding, we need to see that $i\colon G\to i(G)=G\times \{p\}$ is a homeomorphism. It's easy to check that the restriction of $\pi$ to $G\times \{p\}$ is the inverse of $i$, and it is continuous since $\pi$ is continuous. This proves that $i$ is an immersion.

To sum up, we know that $i$ is a smooth embedding with image $G\times \{p\}$. Now, since $\psi\colon G\to G\times \{p\}$ obtained by restricting the range if $i$ is a homeomorphism, give $G\times \{p\}$ the only smooth structure that makes $G\times \{p\}$ a smooth manifold diffeomorphic to $G$. This structure turns $G\times \{p\}$ into an embedded submanifold of $G\times M$, because the inclusion $j\colon G\times\{p\}\to G\times M$ is precisely $i\circ \psi^{-1}$, which is an immersion because it's the composition of immersions.

Hope this helps!